# unable to match string between two tags

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to use regex to match string between two tags. One tag has a random generated number and because of that i am having trouble to find a way of how to match string between two tags.

so i have few strings like this in my html with different name for each string. 
The number you see is randomly generated. and i am trying to get the name for each string

```
<a href="log.jsp?type=Agent&agentIDStr=26444">Amber</a></td>
```

regex i am using

```
<a href="log\.jsp\?type=Agent&agentIDStr=.\d.+">(.*)</a>
```

unfortunately this matches the whole string instead of just the name between the tags. Help appreciated - not a great fan of Regex ;/

Comment: `<a href="log\.jsp\?type=Agent&agentIDStr=\d+">(.*?)</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your regex like below. `\d+` matches one or more digits and `(.*?)` captures zero or more characters non-greedily.

```
<a href="log\.jsp\?type=Agent&agentIDStr=\d+">(.*?)</a>
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/15)

Answer (score 1):

Try simply lazy loading, your are on write track but showing little greediness, ha so try lazy loading. like this

```
 <a href="log\.jsp\?type=Agent&agentIDStr=26444">(.*?)<\/a><\/td>
```

[image]

**N.B:**    `.*?` matches any character (except newline)

```
    Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
```

SEE DEMO:
https://www.regex101.com/r/rA1bL5/1

**More info:**http://javascript.info/tutorial/greedy-and-lazy

Comment: Thanks for input, but its actually Avinash Raj answer that was what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to catch it without regex, in case you were using PHP:

```
$url = '<a href="log.jsp?type=Agent&agentIDStr=26444">Amber</a></td>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($url);

$link = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
parse_str(parse_url($link->getAttribute('href'), PHP_URL_QUERY), $variables);

var_dump($variables); // ['type' => 'Agent', 'agentIDStr' => '26444']
var_dump($link->nodeValue); // Amber
```